# How to get the CSV file generated from SQL store procedure can have text format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

We have a store procedure which generates the csv file from query results. Sometimes when the field gets numeric value, the 0 in the value is truncating as the generated file is in General format. I tried the below query by adding ' infront of the field with 0 so that excel will consider it as a text and the values cannot be truncated...seems doesnt work.

```
select Cust_No as Cust#,'''+SERIAL_NO as Serial#
 from tblCustDetails
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Try the solution depicted here: https://superuser.com/questions/330291/how-to-stop-excel-from-auto-formatting-and-making-it-work-like-a-number-crunchin

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select Cust_No as Cust#,''''+SERIAL_NO as Serial# from tblCustDetails
```

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? If ORACLE, this will work 100%: select Cust_No as Cust#,''''||SERIAL_NO as Serial# from tblCustDetails